# Getting list of nested elements in Angular directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/WM53PPtekoJP7MHYo8Un?p=preview) I have a directive with a list of nested elements ("Value 0", "Value 1", and so on). What I need is to get this list in a directive variable (see scope list). I tried with `transclude` but couldn't figure out. Any ideas?

HTML

```
<directive>
  <ul>
    <li id="0">Value 0</li>        
    <li id="1">Value 1</li>        
    <li id="2">Value 2</li>        
  </ul>
</directive>
```

Javascript

```
angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app')
.directive('directive', function() {

    var directive = {};

    directive.restrict = 'AE';

    directive.scope = true;

    directive.template = "<div>{{list}}</div>";

    directive.link = function(scope, element, attrs) {

    // This is how scope.list should end up         
    // scope.list = [ {id:0, name:"Value 0"}, 
    //                {id:1, name:"Value 1"}, 
    //                {id:2, name:"Value 2"} ];
  };

  return directive;

});
```

Comment: If I have currectly understood your requirements, you could probably have a controller and set `$scope.list` set with the desired array in the controller and use `ng-repeat` over `<ul>` to render the desired html without using the directive.

Comment: No, the objective is to have a directive

Comment: In AngularJS the model creates the view. A directive that creates the model from the view is going backwards.

Comment: @george In the same way you provide as input in a directive a value by declaring it as an element, I need to provide as input an array.

Answer (score 0):

> answer updated v2
>
> I think this is what you want, in this sample we create a directive to bind array from controller.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller("ctrl", function ($scope) {
  $scope.array = [
    {name: "Value 0"},
    {name: "Value 1"},
    {name: "Value 2"}
    ]
})

app.directive("directive", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        transclude: true,
        template: "<div ng-transclude></div>",
        link: function (scope, element) {
            console.log(scope.array)
        }
    };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
  
    <directive>
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="list in array">{{list.name}}</li>
      </ul>
    </directive>
 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No, the array needs to be declared in the directive markup

Comment: No, the directive markup needs to be entered as described in the question